# MediaWiki different site title for different namespaces

Tags: mediawiki

I have found that there is a special MediaWiki page, MediaWiki:Pagetitle, in which I can set the site name to be displayed for all pages between `<title>` tags (default: `$1 - Wiki's_name`). I would like to have different messages depending on the namespace, for example:

- for the main namespace a longer message: `$1 - Wiki's_name, wiki's_subtitle`
- for files the default: `$1 - Wiki's_name`

This is because files usually have a longer name and everything becomes too long.

Is it possible to do this, perhaps with a condition, or doing this from another place rather than using MediaWiki:Pagetitle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `MediaWiki:Pagetitle` to this:

```
{{#switch: {{NAMESPACENUMBER}}
| 6 = $1 - Wiki's_name
| $1 - Wiki's_name, wiki's_subtitle
}}
```

provided that *[ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions)* extension is installed.

Six is the number of `File:` namespace.